# Select2.js Filter Change

Tags: jquery-select2

I have a small issue but I cant seem to find the solution, currently im working on and app that uses Select2.js for DropDowns. It works fine and everything but it is currently filtering data using 'Contains' and I want it to filter using 'StartsWith' but I've looked at the documentation and inside the JS file and cant seem to find how to do it, anyone has any ideas of what should I do?

Thanks for your help!!

```
<input id="select2" class="input-xlarge" data-bind="value: selectedChoice, select2: { choices: choices, optionsValue: 'Id', optionsText: 'Description', placeholder: '--Select a Client--', minimumInputLength: 0, allowClear: true, focusElement: 'ContinueBtn' }, hasfocus: loaded" />
```

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help if you posted some of your code.

Comment: completely forgot to add my code... eddited the question.. ty